# Submission of App on App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, archive

The app is fully tested and ready to submit on app store. I have build IPA using my distribution profile,certificate and bundle identifier.

Now the question is when send this IPA file to client, can client submit app through "application loader" directly?

Does he need to change bundle id, distribution profile and certificate with his own?

Client will definitely login with his own credentials to submit the app.

I have idea of submitting the app but i am confused with the above 2 questions. Kindly suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: when you were creating ur distribution build with XCode5, why don't u opt for the option "Submit to AppStore" from there only.

Comment: I don't have client credentials.

Comment: Then how you will upload app to apstore from you credential to client id

Comment: never.....For this to happen you must have clent credentian and make provisining profile from it account and then you as you want

Comment: he can always create a distribution build with client's certificate and profile as client can export his certificate and can share with the developer alongwith the provisioning profile so Developer does not need explicit access to client's account to generate a distribution build.

Comment: Pretty much logical. I should ask for these things and archive it. He can submit then directly with application loader, is it?

Comment: which zip file? source code or the ipa?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Apple Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html) and [This Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-submit-an-ios-app-to-the-app-store--mobile-16812). It would help you. And i am also answering your questions here..

1. If you have build ipa using your certificates and other stuff than client cant upload it with his own login. Because there is no app in client's account with same bundle identifier.
2. He need to change bundle id, certificates, and distribution profile of his own account.And to build ipa, he must need source code and xcode.

Comment: @samfisher : he clearly mentioned that he has build ipa using his own certificates.. Not using client ones.. And i have not written anything that Developer must need client's login details.. So please review question and answer carefully..